# How to insert html text with text() function?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I need to change the content of an element which includes html.

I tried with this, but the html tags are printed

```
    $('#content-sections label').text('my text <span>a span element</span>');
```

This is printed as it:

> `my text <span>a span element</span>`

Comment: Because you told jQuery to insert this as text... Wanted to post an answer but @Aurelio was faster :)

Comment: This doesn't deserve downvotes. He obviously is new at this and also has trouble asking a question. If people think the question can be improved, **do so by editing** not downvoting. It was pretty obvious what he tried to achieve.

Comment: agreed with timmied, +1

Comment: @Jaso2970 Also welcome to our community, please accept the answer which helps you the most. Other people please stop adding the same answers but just upvote the current correct answers. Three correct answers is **MORE** then enough.

Comment: Upvoted too and didn't downvoted it before.

Comment: @timmied I tried to accept the answer 3 minutes after I posted it. But I get message saying I must to wait 11 minute to do that

Comment: @Jaso2970 It was just a heads up to prevent more double answers;) Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for this. For example:

```
$('#content-sections label').html('my text <span>a span element</span>');
```

Oh, and for better performances, use this instead:

```
$('#content-sections').find('label').html('my text <span>a span element</span>');
```

Comment: ok, I didn't know this function.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#content-sections label').html('my text <span>a span element</span>');
```

But i'm confused with your *"including html text using jquery"*

Answer (score 1):

you have to set with [**html(value) function**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)  which sets the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

```
  $('#content-sections label').html('my text <span>a span element</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like the code below

```
$('#content-sections label').html('my text <span>a span element</span>');
```

`jQuery.html()` treats the string as HTML, `jQuery.text()` treats the content as text that is the reason its printing the `span` tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

Aurelio's answer solves your problem.

But if you need to put a whole structure of html nodes, it's better to use this way:

```
var span = $("<span />").text('a span element');
$('#content-sections label').text('my text').append(span);
```

The first line creates the span with its contents

And the second does 2 things, it first sets the text of the label, then adds the span created in the first line after that text.